# Deleting duplicate entries of a column in data and adding the corresponding values of another column of deleted data together

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have multiple excel files in the same format. i want to remove all duplicates values in the column x. While removing duplicates, i want to add all the values corresponding to the deleted rows in columns a, b and c to be added and put in their respective rows. There are many other columns apart from this, which i want to leave as it is.

```
import pandas as pd

def combine_excel_files(file_paths, output_file='C:/Users/temp/Desktop/Book1.xlsx', max_rows_per_sheet=1048576):
    combined_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for file_path in file_paths:
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

        grouped_df = df.groupby('x', as_index=False).agg({
            'a': 'sum',
            'b': 'sum',
            'c': 'sum'
        })

        df = pd.merge(grouped_df, df.drop(['a', 'b', 'c'], axis=1), on='x', how='left')

        combined_df = pd.concat([combined_df, df], ignore_index=True)
    combined_df = combined_df.sort_values(by='Month')

    sheets = [combined_df.iloc[i:i + max_rows_per_sheet] for i in range(0, len(combined_df), max_rows_per_sheet)]
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        for i, sheet in enumerate(sheets):
            sheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'Sheet_{i + 1}', index=False)`
```

I tried this however, it didn't work

Comment: Please provide a small example of actual data, both where the row is kept intact and where the duplication happens and what values you want to write into the new column.